# Sublime text 2 tab through multiple selection

Tags: sublimetext2

Lets say that I have selected the word 'test' three times using ctr + d.
Is there a way to tab through the selections. So for example if I wanted to go to the second word and only change that one.

I seem to need this quite often but I cannot find it anywhere.
And I also know about the skipping with ctr + d and ctr + k but this is not what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

The [MultiEditUtils](https://github.com/philippotto/Sublime-MultiEditUtils#use-selections-as-fields) package supports this.

Just install the package and bind a key to the `selection_fields` command, e.g.

```js
{ "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "selection_fields" },
```

To use it just create your multiple selection and press the keybinding. Then you can use `tab` and `shift+tab` to tab through the selection. If you tab behind the last one or press `escape`, then the multiple selection will be restored.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I was haven't a horrible time trying to find this. Knew it was out there. Bless you. :D

Comment: @TimothyAaron Actually I added it to MultiEditUtils, because I did not find a convincing way to do this either. :)

Comment: One of these days it'll occur to me that I could just write it myself, too. ;) 
If you're taking requests (or there's already a way to do this I don't know about), I would love to be able to deselect the last selection. I regularly use cmd+d to add the next instance of a selection, but then accidentally add one too many.

Comment: @TimothyAaron You can do this with `soft_undo` (`ctrl+u`)

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I hadn't even tried that. No wonder I couldn't find a package for it. -.-
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is *search*.  Sublime's search is accessed via <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows/Linux), or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Mac).  Sublime's search behaves similarly to many other applications, often web browsers have this feature.  You can use this to cycle through instances until you find the one you were looking for.  If you then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, search will exit and the cursor will stop at the currently selected instance of your word.

See [Sublime's unofficial docs](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace.html) for more details about its full search capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do know the search function :)) but it is not exactly what I mean. But I found a way for me problem. If hit esc then I am back at the first selection again. Then I have to select that first word again and there is the shortcut to go to the next one. It is not as I want it to be but there is no other solution....

Comment: If you hit `enter` you will stay on the current word.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the search
2. Type the term you want to replace
3. Put your cursor at the beginning of your document
4. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to select one
   instance after the other and change it

Comment: In my particular case, it's not always the same text I want to tab between. For instance, if I have a block of code and I want to edit only 3 parts of it, I'd like to multi-select each part, then tab between to edit—instead of click, edit, click, edit, click, edit.